# Rails 2, session & token

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a question-answer survey..

Only one user can answer on survey! User cant click on previous button (in browser) and once again pass the survey. How i can possible do this? I need sessions and unique token? Please help me, i;m stuck with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have user-login, then you only need to validate whether they have already voted or not. This is really required to be 100% sure of no dup votes.

If not, you can't 100% guarantee dup votes, but you could make it difficult:

- store in the session[:voted] = true
- on receiving a vote submission don't accept if session[:voted] == true

Obviously the user can clear cookies which will clear your session.
You could enhance this by logging ip's but then consider proxy-servers (all users from behind the proxy will appear as coming from the same IP -- the proxy).

Answer (score 1):

I you **must** enforce this then I imagine you'd require users to login and then you can store which surveys / survey sections they have already answered in your database.

Otherwise it's generally enough to prevent people from filling in surveys multiple times by storing their ip address in your system and also setting `cookies` on their browser based on which sections they have already completed. They can get around this by clearing their cookies but at least if you store their ip address they'd need to change ip to redo the survey.

It's hard to say without knowing the context of the survey. Is it on an existing app where users already have accounts? Is it standalone etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thnanks guys for respons.
 I thought about this (user-login), but i want to without it.. so i give link address, user get it, click on this address.. like www.blabalbla.com/test/survey/32643928569832569 (unique token).. and user can pass survey.. then when he finished he cant pass this survey again on this link.